# Modifying content in C function with Rust data produces unknown values

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm trying to call a C function in Rust, and I met a strange problem. This code reproduces my problem:

C

```c
int t(uint8_t *data){
    *data = 1;
    *(data+1) = 2;
    *(data+2) = 3;
}
```

```
// block1
unsafe {
    let data = Vec::with_capacity(1024).as_mut_ptr();
    t(data);
    println!("{:?}", Vec::from_raw_parts(data, 4, 4));
}

// block2
unsafe {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(1024);
    let pdata = data.as_mut_ptr();
    t(pdata);
    println!("{:?}", Vec::from_raw_parts(pdata, 4, 4));
}
```

I expect the output to be `[1, 2, 3, 0]`.

Only "block2" works, "block1" outputs `[91, 57, 49, 44]`. I have no idea where that comes from.

The most confusing thing is that when I put "block1" after "block2" and run them together, they both output `[1, 2, 3, 0]` correctly.

What didn't I notice? What's the difference between two blocks?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem (for me it works). Could I ask how do you defined the FFI for t()?

Comment: @attdona `extern { fn t(data: libc::uint8_t);}`, and I use a build.rs to compile it to static lib.

Comment: Try `extern "C" { fn t(data: *mut u8); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* what is happening here is

`let data = Vec::with_capacity(1024).as_mut_ptr();`

This is ends up producing undefined behavior. Here, the `Vec<T>` is temporary, and so will deallocate its memory after this line runs, so you're passing in a bad pointer to the C.

That you get different results when moving code around also seems to imply there's UB here.

Comment: Thanks, that make sense.But I still have a question. I find some detail on internet about the temporary thing, and I found this: [temporary variable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37970#event-870309062). It looks like the same problem as mine, why my compiler didn't  give any error message?  my rustc is ·rustc 1.23.0 (766bd11c8 2018-01-01)·

Comment: Because that’s a reference, but you have a raw pointer here. This is exactly why doing this is unsafe!